# Widget not getting called

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Widget gets called the first time and after popping doesn't get called again

I am trying to create a messaging app , so i am trying to display the last message of the current user with other users. But the items or messages disappear.I found out that it is the buildItem widget that doesn't get called, what might be the cause

Note: I knew it wasn't called cause i put a print statement in it
This is the code

```
                Container(
                  child: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('messages').where('idFrom', isEqualTo: currentid ).snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return StreamBuilder(
                            stream: Firestore.instance.collection('messages').where('idTo', isEqualTo: currentid ).snapshots(),
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              if(!snapshot.hasData){
                                return Center(
                                  child: Text('No Replies Yet'),
                                );}
                              else{
                                return ListView.builder(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildItem(index, snapshot.data.documents[index],context),
                                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length
                                );
                              }
                            }
                        );

                      } else {
                        return ListView.builder(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildItem(index, snapshot.data.documents[index],context),
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                )
            )
```

Sometimes it shows the expected result then disappears , other times it doesn't show at all

Comment: Have you thought about changing the naming of your returned parameters in the StreamBuilder - context and snapshot. Maybe something like snapshot1 and snapshot2 so it knows which builder it is referring to?

Comment: It's easier for us if you have a sample that provides the same unexpected behaviour. with minimal other distracting code. (Like eg the whole `Appbar`, `MaterialApp`, is irrelevant to the question). With that being said the only thing that would explain the Widgets not showing is if the FirebaseStore does not emit items. Did you assert the snapshots are emitted and contain data?

Comment: @LloydNicholson Thanks for your suggestion but it didnt work